# IIS fails with 500 response code

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I've faced with request (/[13:49:32]:й) that leads IIS to fail with 500 error. It contains non-ASCII symbols so I've expected that disabling [High Bit characters](https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/use-request-filtering) should fix it but it doesn't. It seems that [13:49:32] part influences on rewrite module or something else since it tries to load web.config file from another location (\?\E:\sitesroot\0[13:49:32]:й\web.config).

I'm not an expert in IIS but as I understand from poor search results and that stackoverflow also has such issue [https://stackoverflow.com/[13:49:32]:й](https://stackoverflow.com/[13:49:32]:%D0%B9) it is not a well-known issue. So I need some help from IIS guru to fix these errors (replace them with 400).

[image]

Comment: What's the sub status code? Use failed request tracing to find out.

Comment: @LexLi full status code is 500.19 but i didn't find its error code 0x80070459 on [documentation page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942055/-http-error-500.19-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7.0-webpage).

Comment: Only the error page can tell what's up. 500.19 means your configuration file is invalid due to some wrong lines. Dig into the exact error page and it tells.

Comment: @LexLi [Error page](https://postimg.org/image/sy470s2kd/) gave me only an idea about rewrite that I've mentioned in question. But after testing it seems that issue is in [::]:й that could be treated as IPv6 address with port. Trying to get trace logs

Comment: Where did you deploy this web app to? Your own IIS server or an ISP machine? The error line indicates IIS Rewrite module is not even installed.

Comment: @LexLi how do you understand that Rewrite module is not installed? I didn't find that in error description. Moreover it works:

  <Data Name="Pattern">...</Data>
  <Data Name="Input">[13:49:32]:й</Data>
  <Data Name="Negate">false</Data>
  <Data Name="Matched">true</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>PATTERN_MATCH</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>Rewrite</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
 </RenderingInfo>

It is our own IIS server
PS: sorry, I can't manage formatting to work

Comment: All additional information should be added to the original question, not any comment below. Make sure you understand how to play with Stack Overflow. As the module is installed, you can run Process Monitor to monitor file system access, while reproducing this error to see what exactly Windows/IIS does to read this file and fails. That should tell what to check further. Is drive E a mapped drive? (Might not be relevant, but it is also not a great idea to use non-ASCII characters in file path, as not all tools support such without a problem.)